# How to create a zip file with files in FAT format on Linux

Tags: linux, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have to create a zip file (with no compression). I want the files in the zip to be in FAT format. That is, If i use *zipinfo* command, I should get the following:

```
...
    -rw-a--     2.0 fat     3739 b- stor 25-Feb-11 16:46 part0/0072.png
    -rw-a--     2.0 fat     3703 b- stor 25-Feb-11 16:46 part0/0073.png
    -rw-a--     2.0 fat     3751 b- stor 25-Feb-11 16:46 part0/0074.png
    -rw-a--     2.0 fat     3688 b- stor 25-Feb-11 16:46 part0/0075.png
    -rw-a--     2.0 fat     3705 b- stor 25-Feb-11 16:46 part0/0076.png
...
```

To do this I am using the [zip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) command

```
zip -0 -r <archive>.zip <folder>
```

However I am getting the following (when I see with zipinfo)

```
...
    -rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   250847 bx stor  7-Apr-15 01:14 part0/00059.png
    -rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   216029 bx stor  7-Apr-15 01:14 part0/00060.png
    -rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   236572 bx stor  7-Apr-15 01:14 part0/00061.png
    -rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   247082 bx stor  7-Apr-15 01:14 part0/00062.png
    -rw-r--r--  3.0 unx   256374 bx stor  7-Apr-15 01:14 part0/00063.png
...
```

Is there a way to do this using command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `-k` option to your command line:

> **-k
>
>      --DOS-names**
>   Attempt  to  convert  the names and paths to conform to MSDOS, store only the MSDOS attribute (just the user write attribute from Unix), and mark the entry as made under MSDOS (even though it was not); for compatibility with PKUNZIP under MSDOS which cannot handle certain names such as those with two dots.

The `zipinfo` command will show you *fat* and not *unx*.
You can find interesting even the option `-ll`, `-S`

> **-ll
>
>     --from-crlf**
>   Translate  the  MSDOS end-of-line CR LF into Unix LF.  This option should not be used on binary files.  This option can be used on MSDOS if the zip file is intended for unzip under Unix...
>   (read it all)
>
> **-S
>
>    --system-hidden**
>   [MSDOS, OS/2, WIN32 and ATARI] Include system and hidden files.

Notes:

- A zip file created in Linux is compatible with windows: so probably you have not the need to do it.
- The `DOS` format with short names can force the attempt to create more than one path/file with the same name generating errors:

  > zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)

Comment: This solution changes the names, therefor it doesn't work for my specific situation, there should be a flag that keeps the names intact but still makes files show up as "fat" in zipinfo

Answer (score 1):

The zip file should be compatible with windows. The ZIP file is not really in FAT format, which is a disk format, but Linux has more file attributes than window. Eg. Window does not have an executable bit.

Maybe your problem is other. Check: http://usefulmix.com/creating-a-zip-archive-under-linux-that-is-windows-compatible/

Answer (score 0):

[7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to the rescue ...

```
#!/bin/sh

# create zip archive with "fat" filesystem on linux

set -e

# download 7z.exe
# https://www.7-zip.org/download.html
_7z_version=2401
wget https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z$_7z_version-x64.exe
7z x 7z$_7z_version-x64.exe -o7zip_exe

wine64 7zip_exe/7z.exe a -tzip output.zip input1.txt input2.txt
```

... but in my case, `zipinfo` still shows differences

```
-  -rw-a--     6.3 fat   162918 bx defN 15-Jul-11 21:43 backend.js
+  -rw----     2.0 fat   162918 bl defN 15-Jul-11 22:43 backend.js
```

the `a` file attribute means "archive bit"

`6.3` and `2.0` are the zip versions

`bx` means that 7z adds an "extra field". seems like there is no `7z --no-extra`

`man zipinfo`

> if there  is  an  extended  local  header  but  no extra field, ‘l'; if the reverse, ‘x'

also the file time is off by 1 hour

limitation: this is not helpful to reproduce the exact zip archive, since 7zip does not expose the low-level options of the zip format

see also

- https://github.com/drivendataorg/repro-zipfile
- https://github.com/sailro/LLZipLib
- https://github.com/nih-at/libzip
- https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive
- https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/archives/